# Can't install Example42 puppet dashboard module

Tags: puppet, puppet-dashboard

I installed example42 puppet dashboard module using `sudo puppet module install example42-puppetdashboard`, after that I added `class { 'puppetdashboard': }`to **default node** section in **site.pp** and triggered `puppet agent -t`. Everything worked almost good but at the end I got the following error:

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter source failed on File[puppetdashboard.dir]: Cannot use relative URLs '' at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/puppetdashboard/manifests/init.pp:488
```

How can I fix this? Maybe somebody can point me at detailed installation manual.

Comment: Please state your operating system and your full site.pp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a request at GitHub and Example42 guys fixed this problem. It was a bug.
I changed the line in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/puppetdashboard/manifests/site.pp` from `if $puppetdashboard::source_dir {` to `if $puppetdashboard::source_dir and $puppetdashboard::source_dir != '' {`
Here's the [issue](https://github.com/example42/puppet-puppetdashboard/commit/6ff0937f80909b8b698063f2344fccb51d80ffcb) on github.
Anyway, Puppet Dashboard won't work on CentOS 7 which I'm using because there is no such package in CentOS 7 Puppet repo. You have to build it by yourself.